# SAPUI5 DataBinding for sap.m.DatePicker

Tags: data-binding, datepicker, sapui5

How can I bind a DataSet to `sap.m.DatePicker`?
I would like to show a default Date in my DatePicker. The value is coming from a backend oDataService.

I am familiar with binding DataSets to ComboBox items etc, but on Input Fields or a Date Picker this is not working. 
I also tried to attach a dataReceived event in the onInit function, but this event is never called.

Does anybody have a working example for me?

Comment: Can you provide the relevant code in your Controller and View?

Answer (score 1):

Here my exemple:

In the view.xml

```
 <DatePicker id="startDateEvent" displayFormat="short"/>
```

In the controller.js :

```
var startDate = this.byId("startDateEvent");
startDate.setDateValue(<data date from backend>);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to be very careful with the Date and DateTime types. The snippet below works with the dateTime variables in Northwind like [this one for example](https://services.odata.org/V2/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Orders(10248)/OrderDate)

```
<DatePicker value="{path:'yourPathToTheODataProperty', type: 'sap.ui.model.type.Date', formatOptions: { style: 'full'}}"></DatePicker>
```

You can change the format options for a predefined one as explained [here](https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/formatting-dates/) or set your own LDML pattern, as described [here](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.core.format.DateFormat/)